# python/requests_html - Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop

Tags: python, python-requests-html

In below python/requests_html I'm trying to scrape Amazon and get the *Ender 3 3D Printer* with `r.html.xpath("//ul/li[3]/span/span[2]")` but it returns `[]` (I want it to return  `Ender 3`).

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
with HTMLSession() as session:
  r = session.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BR3F9N6')
r.html.xpath("//ul/li[3]/span/span[2]")
```

I added `r.html.render()` because I want to render the web ,but it returns the error

> RuntimeError: Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
with HTMLSession() as session:
  r = session.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BR3F9N6')
  r.html.render() # <--- Issue Here
r.html.xpath("//ul/li[3]/span/span[2]")
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I found the solution:

- Use `Python==3.6`
- Install also chromedriver-py using:  `pip install chromedriver-py`